# partial class is not accessible anymore from the other partial class using Visual 2013 .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-4

I am using .net 4.5.50938
Visual Studio Community 2013 V12.0.31101.00 Update 4
OS: Win 7
I am trying to copy my existing  website from VS2012 to a project/solution in VS2013

---

Using Visual studio I have an Entity Model from database created in place in my 'Models' folder which has partial 'EntityClass1' class as one of its classes.
Now I go to the 'App_Code' folder and I add a class named 'EntityClass1' and I add the same namespace as 'EntityClass1' uses with the key words. But unlike Visual studio 2012 I cannot access EntityClass1's properties!

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyProjectToVs2013.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class EntityClass1
    {
        public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public System.Guid Class1ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Entity34 Entity34 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and in the other EntityClass1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MyProjectToVs2013.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProjectToVs2013.Models
{
    public partial class EntityClass1
    {
        public EntityClass1()
        { 
            //TODO: Add constructor logic here
        }  

        public void createEntityClass1()
        {
//here I am trying to access the properties and unlike VS2012
 I cannot!! there is no such properties available via intelliSense: 
        Title // not appearing!
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: `createEntityClass1` is outside of partial class. which is not valid at all. you cant have method inside namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply actually that was a typo and I edited it. The problem persists.

Comment: Have you done migration successfully? is `csproj` file included? . check if all `cs` files are included. also you should open `sln` file.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  http://rextester.com/OZOO59727

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary as I mentioned I am migrating from website project to a  solution project, so there is no csproj file to include except the newly created one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to go to the EntityClass1 file both in the App_Code and in Model folder
and set the properties called 'NameSpace' for both files to the
"MyProjectToVs2013.Models" and rebuild the project. now it works :)

Source:
 http://dzapart.blogspot.com.tr/2011/11/creating-common-partial-class-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You've placed your method outside the class definition so no members will be available.

Try this:

```
public partial class EntityClass1
{
    public EntityClass1()
    { 
        //TODO: Add constructor logic here
    }

    public void createEntityClass1()
    {
        Title = "anything";
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem persists. In my initial post I had typo, what you typed is exactly what I have but that Title doesn't come up!

Comment: I believe there are certain project configurations that cause App_Code to be treated as text. I may be wrong but please move the class outside of that folder and try again just to be sure.

Comment: well I found the solution finally!!

Comment: I needed to go to the EntityClass1 file both in the App_Code and in Model folder and set the properties called 'NameSpace' for both files to the "MyProjectToVs2013.Models" and rebuild the project. now it works :)
Source :http://dzapart.blogspot.com.tr/2011/11/creating-common-partial-class-with.html

Comment: @Araz please post an answer to your own question and then select it as the answer. That way people who stumble upon this question will be able to find the answer easily.

Comment: Got it! but have to wait 2 days to approve it! tnx